# Linking a .txt file in access and sharing among several users

Tags: ms-access

Here's my dilemma; I had IT create and output a large fixed file from an SQL script that I have linked in my access database. This file is the root object of the entire knowledgebase that I created with dozens of views and reports.

I have several people who can access these reports and data, whether from an Excel query or in the data app forms I've created.

I am trying to figure a way for multiple users to access the data at the same time as read only. Every time someone has it open it is exclusive and cannot be viewed anywhere else until that user closes it.

If someone is viewing a report in access, no one can query from that database while it is open.

Is there any fundamental way I can share this data with multiple users without this huge obstacle while maintaining a link to this .txt file that is automatically updated from a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to link directly to the SQL server that creates the data in the first place. You thus eliminate the time + cost of creating the txt file, and such data can then be shared and used by everyone and used in “real time”.

I mean what happens when data on the SQL server changes? Now your text file is out of date?

Another potential way would be to import the text file into a separate accDB file that your applications/front ends link to.

Again this would provide multi-user ability.

However why go from SQL server (1 system and a storage format) to a text file (a second system and storage format) and then to a possible 3rd format and file as I suggest.

Why not remove all the above steps and simply link the Access application directly to SQL server where the data resides?

The above thus eliminates the need to export the data. The above eliminates the issue of having out of date information, and also gives one multi-user use of that data.

At the end of the day, a “text” file sitting on a computer is NOT a database or information management system and the issues you are having VERY much shows this.

If the output file is not updated often, then again this makes the case for importing the text file into an Access table, and once again you gain multi-user abilities. If such a text file is to be frequent re-created, then you best automate the export process from SQL server to Access if for some reason IT does not want Access users repeatedly pulling data from the SQL server all day long. (so in place of when they create the export text file, you pull the data directly from SQL server into a working Access table).

Comment: "Another potential way would be to import the text file into a separate accDB file that your applications/front ends link to. 

Again this would provide multi-user ability."  Yes I can foresee directly connecting to the SQL an issue at the current time, I get an updated txt every morning in which all analysis is based upon. If I import the txt into a backend, wont I have to manually import every morning? I cant link because that will prevent multi users correct?

Comment: Yes, you would have to manually import the text file into a “throw away” back Access back end. However this import could be automated from the text file into the Access back end file. You are correct one cannot have multi-users link to the text file from Access. As noted, a “live” link to a read only SQL view likely would be the best and most safe, and not require any kind of “daily” import or interaction on your part.